# Auto link property different text with the actual linking (setAutoLinkMask)

Tags: android, hyperlink

For example

```
TextView tv =(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
tv.setText("visit website, http://www.google.com");
```

pressing on http://www.google.com will take me to http://www.google.com.
The thing I want to do is like this

```
TextView tv =(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
tv.setText("visit this website");
```

and pressing on "this" I want to take me to http://www.google.com.

How can I do this ? (is it possible at all ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From API Demo,

```
TextView t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
t3.setText(Html.fromHtml(
                    "<b>text3:</b>  Text with a " +
                    "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">link</a> " +
                    "created in the Java source code using HTML."));
t3.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the attribute `android:text="@string/url"` as the `TextView` attribute. Make sure to put a valid URL as the value of the TextView.