# ListView with multiple lines and hyperlink

Tags: java, android, android-listview, hyperlink

I have a listView with multiple lines and I want to add one more line with a link, but i dont know how to do it.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp83F.png)

this is my code

activity_main.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Custom ListView Example" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/srListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

custom_row_view

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FF00A7FF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cityState"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

SearchResults.java

```html
public class SearchResults {
    private String name = "";
    private String cityState = "";
    private String phone = "";

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setCityState(String cityState) {
        this.cityState = cityState;
    }
    public String getCityState() {
        return cityState;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
}
```

MyCustomBaseAdapter.java

```html
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchResults> results) {
        searchArrayList = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return searchArrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return searchArrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.txtCityState = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cityState);
            holder.txtPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.txtCityState.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getCityState());
        holder.txtPhone.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getPhone());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtCityState;
        TextView txtPhone;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```html
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults = GetSearchResults();

        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.srListView);
        lv.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(this, searchResults));


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Object o = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                SearchResults fullObject = (SearchResults)o;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have chosen: " + " " + fullObject.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<SearchResults> GetSearchResults(){
        ArrayList<SearchResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();

        SearchResults sr = new SearchResults();
        sr.setName("Hospital de Lisboa");
        sr.setCityState("Avenida 123 nº15");
        sr.setPhone("212321234");
        results.add(sr);

        sr = new SearchResults();
        sr.setName("Hospital de Santarém");
        sr.setCityState("Rua de Cima nº20");
        sr.setPhone("234234234");
        results.add(sr);



        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951752/auto-link-property-different-text-with-the-actual-linking-setautolinkmask) answer of use to you? It essentially assigns HTML to the `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

You can't just create a new textview and create new methods to your SearchResults then just sr.setNewLine()?

Comment: what methods? i can write names but i cant put links

Comment: If you just want to make it clickable, you just need to add this attribute to your textview `android:autoLink="web"`